# Socket.lo Connection Not Setup

Tags: android, sockets

I want to setup an Socket.io connection in my android app but it is not being setup. 
Along that i want to send header along with connection.
This code always says connection time out error

```
private static final String SOCKET_URI = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx";
private static final String[] TRANSPORTS = {
        "websocket"
};
    try {
        final IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
        options.transports = TRANSPORTS;
        options.reconnection = true;
        options.port = 5000;
        options.reconnectionAttempts = 10;
        options.reconnectionDelay = 100;
        options.forceNew = true;
        mSocket = IO.socket(SOCKET_URI, options);

        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT,onConnect);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);

        mSocket.io().on(Manager.EVENT_TRANSPORT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Transport transport = (Transport) args[0];
                Log.e(TAG,"Transport Listener "+ args[0].hashCode());

                transport.on(Transport.EVENT_REQUEST_HEADERS, new Emitter.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Object... args) {
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        Map<String, String> headers = (Map<String, String>) args[0];
                        headers.put("xxxxxxxx", "xxxxx);
                })
        });

        mSocket.connect();

    } catch (final URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
   }
}
```

Comment: check your server side code ! if you are using ssl connection or if your want to send headers with your socket see the documentation for socket.io android it explains everything https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

Comment: may be server side they are not accepting your port number as same you are sending. please try to add port number with your url like
SOCKET_URI = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx: 5000"; add 5000 with ":" .

Comment: only connection event is not happening... Rest all of the events(TIME_OUT,RECONNECTING, etc) are happing.

Comment: where is your onConnect method ?